# SQLAlchemy/WTForms: set default selected value for QuerySelectField

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, selection, wtforms

This [example][1] to set up a form with WTForms and SQLAlchemy in Flask and add a QuerySelectField to the form works. I am not using `flask.ext.sqlalchemy`, my code:

```
ContentForm = model_form(Content, base_class=Form)
ContentForm.author = QuerySelectField('Author', get_label="name")
myform = ContentForm(request.form, content)
myform.author.query = query_get_all(Authors)
```

Now I want to **set the default value of the QuerySelectField's selectlist**.

Tried passing a `default` kwarg in QuerySelectField and setting `selected` attributes. Nothing worked. Am I missing something obvious? Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your `default` keyword argument to the instance of `Authors` that you want to be the default:

```
# Hypothetically, let's say that the current user makes the most sense
# This is just an example, for the sake of the thing
user = Authors.get(current_user.id)
ContentForm.author = QuerySelectField('Author', get_label='name', default=user)
```

Alternately, you can provide the instance to the field on instantiation:

```
# The author keyword will only be checked if
# author is not in request.form or content
myform = ContentForm(request.form, obj=content, author=user)
```

Comment: The first method has no effect. The second causes a `TypeError: 'ContentForm' object is not callable` exception...

Comment: @casual - sorry, the second should have been for the instantiation of `myform` - updated.  (As for the first, what happens if you use the `id` of the author ... I don't *think* it should work, looking at the code, but it can't hurt to try it)

Comment: It's strange, the only situation where the select box has the right default is `myform = ContentForm(request.form, author=user)` But then of course all other form fields are empty. Could this be a problem with Flask's requests?

Comment: @casual - I left out the `obj=` that I should have used for `content` - what we need to do is check in `request.form`, and if there is no content there, fill in the form with the data from `obj` (in this case `content`, and if `content` does not have an `author` then use the `author` we provide via keyword arguments.  I have updated my second example and it *should* work now.

Comment: There was a bug somewhere else in my code. Your answer works.

Comment: How do I get the value of selected `QuerySelectField`. For e.g. for my country select dropdown `country = QuerySelectField(query_factory=Country.query.all,
                            get_pk=lambda a: a.id,
                            get_label=lambda a: a.name)` I get the object `<models.Country object at 0xaa1550c>`. How do I get the value of country say 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Since `data` is going to be the actual instance you can just do `your_field.data.id` to get the ID and `your_field.data.YOUR_FIELD_NAME` to get the information in that field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
ContentForm.author = QuerySelectField(
    'Author', 
    get_label="name", 
    default=lambda: Authors.get(current_user.id).one()
)
```