# How to preselected a value of my QuerySelectField Flask in my Update form?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

**Environment:**

Python 3.7.7

Flask 1.1.2

Werkzeug 1.0.1

**Introduction:**

I made a FLask application where my users can add some "Platform" and edit them. Each platform has a category.

For example :

the platform "Facebook" is in the Category "Social Network".

the platform "Instagram" is in the Category "Social Network".

the platform "Google" is in Category "Search Engine".

The New "Platform" and Edit "Platform" use the same form and same template. In this form, there is a QuerySelectField which loads the categories values from a DB query.

When the user wants to edit a "Platform", he opens the "Platform" form where the values of the "Platform" are filled in the fields. This is a typical form that you can found everywhere on internet.

The New "Platform" form works fine.

The Edit "Platform" form is bugging with the QuerySelectField.

I successfully managed to fill the values of "Platform" in the text fields of the "Platform" form, but I have an issue with the QuerySelectField (categories). It doesn't want to preselect the value of the category of the platform.

**Code:**

My forms.py

```
def GetCategories():
    """
    This function is to fill the selectdropdown field of the form NewPlatformForm
    :return:
    """
    return Category.query

class NewPlatformForm(FlaskForm):

    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    category = QuerySelectField('Category', validators=[DataRequired()], query_factory=GetCategories, get_label='name')
    image = StringField('Image',validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=100)])
    description = TextAreaField('Description',render_kw={'rows':20},validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=1200)])
    icon_blue = StringField('Icon blue')
    icon_black = StringField('Icon black')
    icon_white = StringField('Icon white')
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

My routes.py

```
@app.route('/platform/<int:platform_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_platform(platform_id):
    platform = Platform.query.get_or_404(platform_id)
    form = NewPlatformForm()
    platforms_categories = data = db_mysql.session.query(Platform, Category).join(Category).all()
    #IF USER ADD A NEW PLATFORM --------------------------------------------------------
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        platform.name = form.name.data
        platform.category_id = form.category.data
        platform.image = form.image.data
        platform.description = form.description.data
        platform.icon_blue_img = form.icon_blue.data
        platform.icon_white_img = form.icon_white.data
        platform.icon_black_img = form.icon_black.data
        db_mysql.session.commit()
        flash('Your platform has been updated', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('platforms'))
    #IF USER EDIT AN EXISTING PLATFORM --------------------------------------------------------
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        print(f"platform.id_category : {platform.id_category} - {type(platform.id_category)}")
        form.name.data = platform.name
        form.category.data = platform.id_category #Here is the Select field which needs to preselect the Category value of platform.
        form.image.data = platform.image
        form.description.data = platform.description
        form.icon_blue.data = platform.icon_blue_img
        form.icon_white.data = platform.icon_white_img
        form.icon_black.data = platform.icon_black_img

    return render_template('new_platform.html', title='Edit Platform', form=form, legend='Edit Platform',categories=platforms_categories)
```

**What I tried:**

I tried form.category.default instead of form.category.data but it didn't change anything.

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

To prefill the form according to the object (platform), you need to add it to the constructor.
In `edit_platform:`

```
form = NewPlatformForm(obj=platform)
```

Not related but to populate the object from a form, it is easier to use populate_obj (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#wtforms.form.Form.populate_obj)

Comment: Thank you so much to help, but unfortunately, it didn't work. My "Select" list field doesn't have any value preselected. When I print the platform.id_category, I can see I get the correct category id: platform.id_category : 3 - <class 'int'>. But even by passing the value "3" to form.category.data, see screenshot http://prntscr.com/ve169u

Answer (score 0):

I get it!

My QuerySelectField values are from my table Category.
I was trying to pass the category ID as a preselected value of my "SELECT" list field.
This is the wrong way. I had to pass the entire row from table Category instead of the id.

Here is the correct line of code which did the job:

```
form.category.data = Category.query.filter_by(ID=platform.id_category).first()
```

And here is the answer which inspired me to find this solution:

[Flask/WTForms/QuerySelectField - render QuerySelectField with a choice selected based on existing database value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36851172/flask-wtforms-queryselectfield-render-queryselectfield-with-a-choice-selected)