# SQL Alchemy/ Flask / WTF Forms set a default value for a queryselectfield

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I want to set a default value for my queryselectfield. My code looks like this:

Template:

```
{% import "bootstrap/utils.html" as utils %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Request{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="content-section">
...
{{ form.country(class_="selectformfield") }
...
```

Route:

```
@requests.route('/request/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_request():

check_admin()

add_request = True

form = RequestForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    ...
    Country = form.hostname.data
    ...

    request = Request(...country=country, ...)

    try:
        # add request to the database
        db.session.add(request)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You have successfully added a new request.')
    except:
        # in case request name already exists
        flash('Error: request already exists.')

    # redirect to the request page
    return redirect(url_for('requests.show_request', id=request.id))

# load request template
return render_template('requests/add_request.html', add_request=add_request,
                       form=form, title='Add new Request')
```

Form:

```
class RequestForm(FlaskForm):
...
country = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Country.query.all(), get_label="name")
...
```

I already tried it like this, but it didn't work.

```
default_country = query_factory=lambda: Country.query.filter(Country.id == '1')
country = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Country.query.all(), get_label="name", default=default_country)
```

[SQLAlchemy/WTForms: set default selected value for QuerySelectField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579373/sqlalchemy-wtforms-set-default-selected-value-for-queryselectfield)
I also already read this post here with a simmilar problem, but the solution doesn't work for me. 
Can annyone help me?

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem? Do you see any errors? Try to change `FlaskForm` to `from flask_wtf import Form`

Comment: There was no error when executing my approach. It just didn't set the value with the id 1 as default. 
Unfortunately this is a work related problem and I can't access the code until next week, but I'm definitely  gonna try your suggestion then and will get back to you.

Comment: By the way could you add your template + route to question?

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I edited the post above and added the code. Your first suggestion didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
default=lambda: Country.query.filter(Country.id == '1').one_or_none())
```

here the complete code of your field definition:

```
country = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Country.query.all(), get_label="name", default=lambda: Country.query.filter(Country.id == '1').one_or_none())
```